# Is it okay to call Doctrine's flush at the end of every request?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

From what I know of Doctrine and its `flush` command, the Entity Manager builds up a collection of changes to the entities with the `persist` method, propagating changes to related entities, while building up a 'persist query' ready for those changes to be commited the database when `flush` is called.

If my understanding is correct, does it make sense then to have some kind of application hook (my application is a ZF2 app, but it could be any MVC application) that calls `flush` at the end of every request? Is this how `flush` is meant to be used anyway (I've never seen anything like this in docs or blog posts)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application there will be no problems calling the flush() method at the end of every request. But I think you have to look at this as transactions, you should control your transactions inside your model layer (or in your controllers depending), not as hooks. That's not the purpose of a transaction, right? You should be able to control each transaction of your application instead of having just one single transaction for everything.